# JQuery IE Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, object, methods, internet-explorer-7

I've been trying to debug this the whole day but can't seem to find why it's not working on IE7+.  It's working fine on other browsers except IE7+

Here's the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#bigbox_carousel').rotator({
    width: 490,
    height: 210,
    duration: 'slow',
    rotate: 5000,
    selected: 0
  });
  $('#bigbox_links').rotator({
    before: 1,
    after: 1,
    width: 220,
    height: 70,
    direction: 'up',
    duration: 'slow',
    rotate: 5000,
    selected: 0
  });
});
```

The error is pointing to the 2nd line of the code.  I already did some deep research and none of the solutions I found worked.

Comment: Which plugin is this? Care to provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe need to set the width and heights using actual units, like 490px and 210px, etc.?

Comment: I tried adding actual units but it didn't work.  Here's a copy of the JS file.

http://arnelestanislao.com/moontoast/jquery-rotator.js

Comment: Finally fixed it.  There was an extra comma on the JS file in line 59. :-)